# Как перемножить значение полей "Вес"?

Tags: jquery

Как перемножить значение поля "Вес" именно с тем  пробы, у которого нет класса uk-hidden? Пока не получилось реализовать даже по событию click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var gold = $("select[name=gold]").val() * 1;
  var silver = $("select[name=silver]").val() * 1;
  var weight = $("input[name=weight]").val() * 1;

  // Показываем список проб и цену за грамм при загрузке
  if ($("select[name=metal]").val() == "gold") {
    $('select[name=silver]').addClass('uk-hidden');

    $("span.value").text(gold);
    $("span.result").text(gold * weight);
  } else {
    $('select[name=gold]').addClass('uk-hidden');

    $("span.value").text(silver);
    $("span.result").text(silver * weight);
  }
});

$(function() {
  var gold = $("select[name=gold]").val() * 1;
  var silver = $("select[name=silver]").val() * 1;
  var weight = $("input[name=weight]").val() * 1;

  // Отображаем список проб
  $("select[name=metal]").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "gold") {
      $('select[name=silver]').addClass('uk-hidden');
      $('select[name=gold]').removeClass('uk-hidden');
    } else {
      $('select[name=gold]').addClass('uk-hidden');
      $('select[name=silver]').removeClass('uk-hidden');
    }
  })

  // Расчитываем
  $("a[name=send]").click(function() {
    if ($('select[name=silver]').hasClass("uk-hidden")) {
      var result = gold * weight;
    } else {
      var result = silver * weight;
    }

    $("span.value").text(gold);
    $("span.result").text(result);
  });
});
```

```css
.uk-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="uk-form">
  <fieldset>
    <select name="metal" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-bottom">
      <option value="gold">Золото</option>
      <option value="silver">Серебро</option>
    </select>

    <select name="gold" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-bottom">
      <option value="2500">999</option>
      <option value="2400">958</option>
      <option value="2200">850</option>
      <option value="2000">750</option>
      <option value="1600">585</option>
      <option value="1600">583</option>
      <option value="900">375</option>
      <option value="2000">56</option>
    </select>

    <select name="silver" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-bottom uk-hidden">
      <option value="35">925</option>
      <option value="27">875</option>
      <option value="18">750</option>
      <option value="15">500</option>
      <option value="100">84</option>
    </select>

    <input name="weight" type="text" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-bottom" value="2" placeholder="Вес">

    <a name="send" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-primary">Рассчитать</a>

    <p>Цена за грамм <span class="value">___</span> руб.</p>
    <p>Сумма на руки <span class="result">___</span> руб.</p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас, судя по вашему коду, цена за грамм и количество грамм устанавливается по загрузке страницы и в процессе работы не меняется (при нажатии "Рассчитать"). Получение этих значений необходимо осуществлять по событию нажатия:

```js
$("a[name=send]").click(function() { 
 gold = $("select[name=gold]").val() * 1;
    silver = $("select[name=silver]").val() * 1;
    weight = $("input[name=weight]").val() * 1;
 
    if ($('select[name=silver]').hasClass("uk-hidden")) {
      var result = gold * weight;
    } else {
      var result = silver * weight;
    }

    $("span.value").text(gold);
    $("span.result").text(result);
});
```

P.S.

`$(document).ready(function() {` и `$(function() {`

выполняют одну и туже роль. Второе - краткий аналог первого.

Comment: По такому же принципу можно сделать расчет на изменение полей?

Comment: Да, по такому же принципу можно делать расчет при изменении полей. Вешаем обработчик на изменение поля, в нем получаем текущие значения полей и на их основе рассчитываем.